# Depth Stencil Buffer

Tags: opengl, graphics-programming

In OpenGL, what is the difference between GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT and GL_DEPTH_STENCIL?
I have looked around and have been unable to find a clear explanation.

Information on their usage with GLSL would also be appreciated (mainly DEPTH_STENCIL).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you require an explanation of the stencil itself or just these constants?

Comment: I'd like to know if it possible to use it with GLSL samplers? Currently I access depth using the r channel, and want to know if the stencil can be used through the alpha channel.

Comment: Also, do you have to use glStencilMask, or can the value of the stencil be set directly through shader output?

Comment: The stencil is not explicitly readable or writable. Instead, it can be configured to track a number of "statistics" about all draw() calls since clear() (configured for writes) and/or "filter" the pixels that are affected by all future draw() calls (configured for reads).

Comment: [This has a few examples explained](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stencil_buffer)

Comment: I see how this can be useful, but doesn't fit what i need it for. Thanks for taking time to answer my question.

Comment: No problem; I added a stencil diagram anyways.

Comment: Hey, there is a different method of sampling a textured quad, located in 3D space, that produces stencil-like effects without using THE stencil. Reference [my answer here](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/98319/draw-many-flashlights-focused-lights-circles-on-a-voxel-engine-map-and-othe/98337#98337). The pixel filtering could definitely be alpha-based.

Answer (score 3):

It is typical to use a 32-bit depth-buffer:

```
GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F //internal format
GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT    //depth only
GL_FLOAT              //float(32-bit depth)
```

If you also wish to utilize the stencil buffer, it is typical to dedicate 8 of those 32-bits to the stencil:

```
GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8   //internal format
GL_DEPTH_STENCIL      //depth + stencil
GL_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8  //ushort(24-bit depth) + uchar(stencil)
```

If you require 32-bit precision for depth, but also require the stencil:

```
GL_DEPTH32F_STENCIL8               //internal format
GL_DEPTH_STENCIL                   //depth + stencil
GL_FLOAT_32_UNSIGNED_INT_24_8_REV  //float(32-bit depth) + ushort(spare) + uchar(stencil)
```

Refer to the [last chart under "Description"](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml).

Stencil diagram:

[image]